# Python loop keeps stopping in Window's interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, loops, pythoninterpreter

I'm using the default Python 3.8 interpreter in Windows.

Whenever I run a long loop in it, it'll stop and I have to press or hold down the Enter key for it to keep going. This was never a problem in Linux.

How do I fix this behavior?

```
# this loop will eventually stop/hang/pause forever, until I press the Enter key
for i in range(5000):
   time.sleep(1)
   print(i)
```

If I run the code through any IDE, it doesn't pause. But I want to run this particular code directly in the interpreter for my own reasons.

I took this screenshot after waiting more than 1 minute for it to continue. This isn't a once off problem. ANY loop I run, no matter how small or big or complex, will permanently stop after a few iterations until I press the ENTER key on my keyboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know if it has stopped/paused? This will take 5000 seconds to run.

Comment: What is your evidence of "forever"?  This is a loop that simply sleeps for over 80 minutes, one second at a time.  There is no output, no input, ...

Comment: @HarshalParekh This isn't what's happening, I fixed my silly example

Comment: @Prune I fixed my example

Comment: @Jase this is still not a good example. It’ll keep on pruning 5000 “1”s. Replace it with print(i) and you’ll see that there is no problem with the code.

Comment: @HarshalParekh The code stops as I said. Whether I print 1, i, or do any other operation. The problem isn't with the code, as I said it works in any IDE (I've tried Wind, Pycharm). The problem is when I run it inside the Windows interpreter. If I run it on my Ubuntu box in the terminal, it works fine.

Comment: @HarshalParekh I just attached a screenshot

Comment: @Jase - strange, I am unable to replicate this on my windows machine, maybe someone who can replicate this can help you.

Comment: Voting to close that it’s not actually a problem as stated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console will pause the script if you click on the output, it will try to stop the code to "select" a part of the output. give it a try without clicking it. ENTER will remove focus from the select bar on the console, so you will see that the it's not there anymore.

Comment: This simply means that there’s no error in the interpreter. If it’s true then the question has wrong information. It nowhere mentions that it stops after the first keyboard input. I am voting to close the question as not reproducible or caused by typo.

Answer (score 1):

The program you have shown will literally do nothing. It won't print anything to console and doesn't wait for input.

So it will literally run for 83 minutes not showing that it is doing anything and then it will exit with a exit code of 0.

Comment: This isn't what's happening, I fixed my silly example

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. So I had this issue before as well. It had to do with how windows command line works since that is what python uses when you run it directly. If you click your mouse on any line above where the cursor is it will freeze the program. When you hit enter you tell the command line you want to go to cursor and it resumes. Give this a try. If you want to bring the window to the fore ground of your desktop click the taskbar of the window rather than on the window itself. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: If it just pauses without you clicking it then I'm unable to reproduce your error with `python 3.8.3 Windows 10 64-bit`

Comment: If quick-edit mode is enabled in the console, then clicking anywhere on the console screen switches to select mode. You'll see the title bar updated to start with "Select" (localized, of course). When `print` writes to `sys.stdout`, if it's a console screen-buffer file, then internally it calls `WriteConsoleW`. In select mode, the latter blocks until the user exits select mode by pressing a key such as escape to end the selection or enter to copy the selection to the clipboard. This is a convenience for the user in select mode, but how easy it is to enable it with a single click is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess at what you are running into.

Of course, the program continues to run, but you just did not see the output, because the output is buffered and you don't flush it.

So, after each `print(i)`, call the function `flush_output_streams()`:

```
def flush_output_streams() -> None:
    """
    flushes the output streams.

    flush calls are wrapped in try ... except, because 
    standard streams might be replaced with other streams which 
    dont have the flush method.
    """
    try:
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except Exception:
        pass
    try:
        sys.stderr.flush()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function also accepts a `flush` parameter, which can be set to `True` so "that the stream is forcibly flushed".

Comment: @Gino Mempin: thanks for the edit - I prefer to flush explicitly at certain stages of the program, because I also need to flush the streams for logging (StreamHandler).
On Linux there is usually no problem, but on some windows machines it can take a long time until the output streams are getting flushed by itself.